# Workflow: git-repository with sub-modules to release

Tags: git, workflow, version, git-submodules, trunk

My git project (a Wordpress-Plugin) contains some 3rd party submodules with extra files (language `.po` files, `/tests` folder, `coverage.cover`) that are not needed in release versions.

Is there a command/workflow that strips all of these files automatically for releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release management process differs from the source control management (here Git and its submodule)

If your deployment process is to simply checkout the content of a Git repo (and its submodule, with a `git submodule update --init --recursive`), then no, there is nothing native to Git that would strip out the non-needed part of those subrepos.
You would need to call an additional script (made for fine-tuning the deployment), which would take care of that step.